# keycloak-js appending session data to url in vue3

Tags: url, vuejs3, keycloak, vue-router

`keycloak-js` appears to be appending session data when I refresh my vue3 application: `https://my.domain/#/&state={state}&session={session}` etc

I wouldn't have a problem with this except it's breaking my site when I refresh due to the incorrect url format.

I can't find where this appears to be trying to append the data in the url from.

Comment: Issue on Keycloak Github: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14742

Answer (score 3):

It ended up being that `keycloak-js` appears to conflict with `createWebHashHistory` in vue-router. I've updated it to just use `createWebHistory` and now my site is working.

There is logic in `keycloak-js` that tries to determine if you're in a query string and I found the problem by stepping through that code in `parseCallbackUrl`.

**Example:** As stated, I ended up using `createWebHistory` instead of `createWebHashHistory`. I made the change in my `router/index.js` file in the `createRouter` method passing the history option:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

/* Other router code here */

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(), // was createWebHashHistory() with matching import substitution
    routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Can you provide code example ?

Comment: I used createWebHistory(), keycloak-js is still appending session data to all my paths & breaking them whenever I refresh.

Comment: @lime_ajinomoto I think I'd need an example url of how it's breaking. are you sure you don't have a duplicate url param or something like that?

Comment: @interesting-name-here It was redirecting me to 502 page on refresh, I found out why. 

It was because my Realm name together with Keycloak's session data in the path made the URL too long. My workaround was to shorten my Realm name & then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround to configure in router configuration. Credits from [this thread](https://github.com/dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js/issues/94#issuecomment-1120791906).

```
const removeKeycloakStateQuery = (to, from) => {
  const cleanPath = to.path
    .replace(/[&\?]code=[^&\$]*/, "")
    .replace(/[&\?]state=[^&\$]*/, "")
    .replace(/[&\?]session_state=[^&\$]*/, "");

  return { path: cleanPath, query: {}, hash: to.hash };
};

// ...
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("src/pages/component.vue"),
    beforeEnter: [removeKeycloakStateQuery],
  }
```